# In org-mode: Open attachment with one keystroke

Tags: emacs, org-mode

As I want to open attachment files with one keystroke, I am looking for a keybinding that basically does the same as `org-attach o` or `C-c C-a o`, respectively. This should work in org files and the agenda.

I defined this keybinding `(global-set-key (kbd "<f9>") 'org-attach-open)`, but this is not working in the agenda, prompting `Need absolute ’org-attach-directory’ to attach in buffers without filename`.

Minimal working example to reproduce this: In your agenda, move the point on a line with an attachment and execute `M-x org-attach-open`.

How do I define a key binding that does exactly `org-attach o`, not regarding from where I am calling it?

Comment: The `org-mode` and `org-agenda-mode` have different keyboard maps, so you'll need two keyboard shortcuts -- and they are not global.  Google `org-mode-map` and `org-agenda-mode-map` and `define-key` and `org-mode` and `org-agenda-mode`.  There should be about a zillion threads on the issue.  If you do not find an example using `eval-after-load`, then Google that also.  Or, use `require` (which causes the whole library to load when Emacs starts):  `(require 'org-agenda) (define-key org-agenda-mode-map "t" 'butterfly)`

Comment: In terms of the other issue (probably [?] unrelated to the keyboard shortcut issue) about receiving a prompt for an absolute attachment directory, it may be helpful to provide a minimal working example so that forum readers can reproduce the issue and then suggest a solution.  The doc-string states in relevant part:  "*If there are more than one attachment, you will be prompted for the file name. ...*"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, lawlist. `(with-eval-after-load "org" (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<f9>") 'org-attach-open))` works for org-mode as expected. Nevertheless, defining it for org-agenda-mode-map, i.e. `(with-eval-after-load "org-agenda" (define-key org-agenda-mode-map (kbd "<f9>") 'org-attach-open))` returns the same error message on execution as mentioned in the original question. I updated the original question by a minimal working example.

Comment: Is using an absolute path for the `org-attach-directory` a possibility in your particular setup, or do you believe that only a relative path will suit your needs?  If the former is acceptable, then add a line to your `org-mode` configuration for `(setq org-attach-directory "/absolute/path/to/data/directory/")` -- the forward trailing slash is default, so I would follow that same format.  If you must have only relative paths, then it appears that `org-attach-open` is not designed to work in `*Org Agenda*` (non-file-visiting buffers) unless an absolute path to the aforementioned directory exists

Comment: Yes, I need the realitive path as I am having agenda files in different paths with different local data directories. This is why I am looking for “a keybinding that basically does the same as `org-attach o` or `C-c C-a o`, respectively”. These do work in the agenda...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user selects the letter `o` after calling `org-attach` from an `*Org Agenda*` buffer, the user has technically already left the `*Org Agenda*` buffer (even though this is done under the hood).  Therefore, we need a new function that does the same thing as `org-attach` before running `org-attach-open`.

```lisp
(defun org-agenda-attach-open ()
"My doc-string."
(interactive)
  (unless (eq major-mode 'org-agenda-mode)
    (let ((debug-on-quit nil))
      (signal 'quit '("This was written expressly for `*Org Agenda*`."))))
  (let ((marker (or (get-text-property (point) 'org-hd-marker)
                    (get-text-property (point) 'org-marker))))
    (if marker
      (save-excursion
        (set-buffer (marker-buffer marker))
        (goto-char marker)
        (org-back-to-heading t)
        (call-interactively 'org-attach-open))
      (error "No task in current line"))))
```